# avoid function closure in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, closures

I want to link a callback to each *input* (type text) with class 'liveVariable':

```
$(".liveParameter").keyup(function(){
    var callBackString= 'skp:change-'+$(this).attr('id')+'@'+$(this).attr('value');
    window.location = callBackString;               
});
```

However, this gives me a strange error. The value passes is the initial value of the input field (every time the event is fired).

I don't understand why this doesn't work. I dont think I have a closure, the local variable callBackString is created *in* the called function. So it should be created every time over?

How can I solve this in an elegant manner? (I would not like to create a call for each input field, cause I have many live parameters..)

Comment: Change `$(this).attr('value')` to `$(this).val()`

Comment: Also, just for the sake of my OCD, change `$(this).attr("id")` to `this.id`

Comment: Interesting @Archer...benefits?

Comment: @ChrisKempen The benefits of not constructing a huge jQuery object just to get the id of the element which can be accessed directly with `this.id`? :)

Comment: But the `$` looks so pretty! xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change in your code

```
$(this).attr('value'); // get the initial value

$(this).val(); // get the current and updated value
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FjgLB/

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
var callBackString= 'skp:change-'+$(this).attr('id')+'@'+$(this).attr('value');
```

...to:

```
var callBackString= 'skp:change-'+$(this).attr('id')+'@'+$(this).val();
```

More detail on the `.val()` function can be found on the [jQuery docs website here](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

***Edit:***

For the sake of elegance, performance, and comment contribution, the following solution would ultimately be the best:

```
$(".liveParameter").keyup(function(){
    var input = $(this);
    var callBackString = 'skp:change-' + input.attr('id') + '@' + input.val();
    window.location = callBackString;
});
```